# Remove file from directory - ext-like file system implementation

Tags: c, filesystems

I have an issue. I'm currently trying to implement an ext-ish file system. I've done the inode operations such as read and write. I've created a structure that represents both a regular file and a directory. I have a problem when trying to remove a certain file from the directory.

```
char
dirremove(struct dirent *dir, struct dirent *file)
{
    dirent_t n = {.mode = NODDIR, .inumber = remdirnod, 
                      .r = 0, .w = 0};
    strcpy(n.nm, dir->nm);
    dirent_t t;
    dir->r = 0;
    char r = 1;

    while (!dirread(dir, &t))
    {
        int tt = dir->r;
        dir->r = 0;
        dirent_t ff[3];
        filread(ff, dir, 3 * entrysiz);
        dir->r = tt;

        if (!strcmp(t.nm, ""))
            return 1;
        if (!(!strcmp(t.nm, file->nm) && !(r = 0)))
            assert(!dirappend(&n, &t));
    }
    assert(n.w == dir->w - entrysiz);
    dir->w = n.w;
    dir->r = n.r;
    copyinode(dir->inumber, remdirnod);
    return r;
}
```

This is the function called from the *rm* command. It takes the directory object (where the file is stored) and the file object to be deleted. I know this solution is not the best in terms of speed and memory usage but I'm still a beginner in this area, so don't hate me a lot, please :).

The function is designed to do the following. It has to read all files and check if the current is the one to be deleted. If not, the file is added to a new directory (empty in the beginning) which will replace the old one at the end of the function. The "new" directory is an entry saved entirely for this purpose, so there isn't a chance that all inodes are already used.

The test that I've done is to create a file (works fine), then remove it, then create it again and remove it. Everything works perfectly except for the second execution of the *dirremove* function. The directory has its *dot* and *dot-dot* directories by default so it goes through them first. The result is that the first deletion is successful. Everything works perfectly. But the second time things go wrong somewhere.

```
int tt = dir->r;
dir->r = 0;
dirent_t ff[3];
filread(ff, dir, 3 * entrysize;
dir->r = tt;
```

I added the *ff* array that should read the whole content of the directory and this would help me figure out if the correct files are there. On the first and second iteration, all files (".", ".." and "some-other-file") are there but at the iteration which should hold the object of the file that's to be removed the third file suddenly goes all zeroes.

I've debugged this for several hours but it continues to fail the same way.

Probably I didn't explain the failure the best way, but there are a lot of things that I forgot to say, so if I missed something please don't ignore the question and just ask about it.

Comment: `dirent_t` and `dirread` are already identifiers in POSIX. You misdirect many readers using something already taken by POSIX. Also you introduce name clashes. Don't do it, please rename your symbols. `assert(!dirappend(&n, &t))` - don't use expressions with side effects inside `assert`, it is removed on release builds - ie. those that don't define `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Sensible variable names would also help. `int r` should be something like `bool first_entry`.

Comment: I'm not sure that `if (!(!strcmp(t.nm, file->nm) && !(r = 0)))` does what you want. `!(r = 0)` is always true, so it doesn't affect the result of `&&`. Can you explain what logic you're trying to implement there?

Comment: @Barmar I use the ability that if the first expression is false, the. second won't be evaluated. So _! (r = 0)_ will be executes when the names are the same

Comment: @Barmar [Show-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Why not use a normal `if` statement? `if (strcmp(t.nm, file->nm) != 0) { r = 0; }`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @b0kiii It's **short** circuit. All the `!` make that expression overly complicated, I had to work out the meaning on paper. Use de Morgan's Law to simplify the double negatives.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the proposal. I'll change it immediately.